# Functional equations of $\lambda(\tau)$

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

We have the elliptic lambda function: $$\lambda(\tau)=\frac{e_3-e_2}{e_1-e_2}$$ We want to look at how $\lambda$ changes under a modular transformation: $$\omega'_2=a\omega_2+b\omega_1$$ $$\omega'_1=c\omega_2+d\omega_1$$ Now for $a$ and $d$ odd and $b$ and $c$ even we have $$\lambda\left (\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}\right )=\lambda(\tau)$$ Taking matrices outside of this we can just look at $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ as all other matrices in question can be composed with these. The first gives $$\lambda(\tau+1)=\frac{\lambda(\tau)}{\lambda(\tau)-1}$$ However I am having trouble with the second matrix. I have since $a=0$, $b=1$, $c=1$, $d=0$ that we have $\omega_2'\equiv \omega_1$ and $\omega_1'\equiv \omega_2$. And therefore this means that $e_1$ and $e_2$ are interchanged. Hence we have that $$\tau'=\frac{\omega_2'}{\omega_1'}=\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}=\frac{1}{\tau}$$ Or that $$\lambda\left( \frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}\right )=\lambda\left ( \frac{1}{\tau}\right )$$ Therefore $$\lambda\left (\frac{1}{\tau}\right )=\frac{e_3-e_1}{e_2-e_1}=1-\frac{e_3-e_2}{e_1-e_2}=1-\lambda(\tau)$$

However looking at wolfram alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lambda(-1%2Ftau)
  and Ahlfors complex analysis text they give the equation as

> $$\lambda\left (-\frac{1}{\tau}\right )=1-\lambda(\tau)$$ Where does the negative sign come from? Surely permuting $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ just means we have $\frac{1}{\tau}$ without the minus? Sorry for the long explanation.

Comment: Are you aware that $\det \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} = -1$ and that $\tau \to \frac 1 \tau$ sends the upper half plane to the bottom half plane, where $\lambda$ is not defined ?

Comment: I didn't realise that the determinant reflected the transformation into the lower half plane. Why is this?

Comment: $ad-bc$ has the same sign as the derivative of the transformation on the real axis. Since the real axis is sent to the real axis, it flips the two half planes iff the derivative there is negative.

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand it. If you could move your comment to an answer I can give you the bounty. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, having determinant $-1$, flips the two half-planes, and is not in the modular group.

As such, it doesn't really make sense to try to relate $\lambda(\frac 1 \tau)$ and $\lambda(\tau)$ since they are never defined at the same time.

The modular group is generated by $\tau \mapsto \tau +1$ and $\tau \mapsto -\frac 1 \tau$, and the corresponding effects on $\lambda$ are respectively $\lambda \mapsto \frac \lambda {\lambda-1}$ and $\lambda \mapsto 1 - \lambda$, both of order $2$.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only award the bounty after 24 hours but I'll make sure I do award it